# latexmk stops during execution

Tags: latexmk, vscode, latex-workshop

I am using latexmk directly or calling from VS Code via Latex-workshop.
It runs normally from the terminal but seems to be terminated prematurely when running from Latex-workshop.

The output stops like this:

```
Rule classification: 
  Requested rules:
  pdflatex
  Pre-primaries:
  bibtex AlignPeopleMethod
  Primary:
  pdflatex
  Post-primaries:
  NONE
  Inner-level one_time rules:
  NONE
  Outer-level one_time rules:
  view
Make: doing pre_primary and primary...
  Make for rule 'bibtex AlignPeopleMethod'
  Make for rule 'pdflatex'
Make: doing post_primary...
Rule classification: 
  Requested rules:
  p
```

please note the cut-off single letter p.

It once surprised me by finishing, resulting in:

```
Rule classification: 
  Requested rules:
  pdflatex
  Pre-primaries:
  bibtex AlignPeopleMethod
  Primary:
  pdflatex
  Post-primaries:
  NONE
  Inner-level one_time rules:
  NONE
  Outer-level one_time rules:
  view
Make: doing pre_primary and primary...
  Make for rule 'bibtex AlignPeopleMethod'
  Make for rule 'pdflatex'
Make: doing post_primary...
Rule classification: 
  Requested rules:
  pdflatex
  Pre-primaries:
  bibtex AlignPeopleMethod
  Primary:
  pdflatex
  Post-primaries:
  NONE
  Inner-level one_time rules:
  NONE
  Outer-level one_time rules:
  view
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date
For rule 'update_view', use internal command '&do_update_view( 1 1 0 1 )' ...
Rule classification: 
  Requested rules:
  pdflatex
  Pre-primaries:
  bibtex AlignPeopleMethod
  Primary:
  pdflatex
  Post-primaries:
  NONE
  Inner-level one_time rules:
  NONE
  Outer-level one_time rules:
  view

=== Watching for updated files. Use ctrl/C to stop ...
```

Does anyone have an idea what the issue could be?

```
MacOS 13.2.1
Tex Live 2023
LaTeX-Workshop v9.8.1
latexmk 4.79
VS Code 1.76.2
```